# Multiple input tables for Add Field in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, modelbuilder

My model requires `field1` to be added to `fc1` and `fc2`, and then calculated according to a Python expression `calc1`. `field2` is then added to `fc2`, and calculated using `calc1`. How do I add the multiple feature classes as the input to Add Field and Calculate Field? I have tried creating an input table variable as a list of values, and while it accepts `fc1` and `fc2` when I type it in, the model does not run ("dataset does not exist").

**edit** I'm adding these fields so that I can join the tables on a common pre-existing field and populate `fc2.field1` with the values from `fc1.field1`.

[image: model screenshot]

Comment: Can you add a picture of your model please?  It is perfectly possible to add a list of feature classes to the functions you describe, so I think something else is going on.

Comment: Iterators or Python loops are a must for repetative tasks (I prefer the programming method for reusablility with other projects).

Comment: @SylvesterSneekly I've added an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `Add Field` twice? First for `fc1` and then another block for `fc2`.
Add Field tool accepts only single table/feature class as input.

It will look similar to: [image: Add Field example]

If you have many feature classes and want to add field to each of them then you can use [iterators](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000001n000000.htm) in ModelBuilder (take a look at "Iterate Datasets" section) or convert to python script and use loops if you are convenient with python.

Comment: Yes I did have `Add Field` three times, but it seemed a bit ridiculous to have three copies of the exactly the same process. Was hoping there was a way to make the model more streamlined. I'll take a look at the iterators, though for only two feature classes I'm not sure if it is worth it for this exercise. Would be useful for the future though. Thanks

Comment: You should only need two add fields (one for field1 and one for field2).  The first takes a list and the second (as you describe it) takes just fc2.  You then need two calculate fields (one for Field1 and one for Field2).  I don't think an iterator will help you a great deal here

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear, there are two `Add Field` processes to add `field1` to `fc1` and `fc2`, and a third `Add Field` to add `field2` to `fc2`. Calculate Field is then run on `fc1.field1` and `fc2.field2`.

Comment: Yes - you can do the first one using a list (or ought to be able to)

Comment: After consulting with a colleague, he confirmed that for each `Add Field` operation, I would have to copy and paste the block for each input. Thanks for bringing iterators to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a field to multiple FeatureClasses, you are still going to have to add the "Add Field" tool into both FC "chains".  However, if you want to simply define the characteristics of the field once and apply it to multiple "Add Field" tools, you can call things like Field Name, Field Type, and Field Length out as model Parameters and apply them to multiple Add Field tools, as shown below.

Right-click on Add Field-->Make Variable-->From Parameter-->choose a model characteristic to expose.  In this example, the parameter will not be exposed through the user dialog, just to setting through modelbuilder and re-using in multiple tools.

[image: Re-using model parameters for multiple tools]

Comment: I did have the characteristics exposed initially, which is how I got to this question as I had three copies of each process (and therefore four properties were exposed in triplicate). I do like this concept though, as it would allow me to change the name of the field to be added to each table once only, rather than having to change it in each copy of the process.